# When to use ShapeRenderer & SpriteBatch in libGdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

As a beginner(in GdxLib+Android), i found that for rendering particular screen, we can render that using both ways then when to use specific ones? 
&
**What is the best option for Updating the smaller part/region of the screen**?

Answer (score 5):

per documentation `ShapeRenderer` isn't efficient and shouldn't be used intensively.

> Renders points, lines, rectangles, filled rectangles and boxes. This class is not meant to be used for performance sensitive applications but more oriented towards debugging.

That being said, I asked for opinions on its real impact [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49671/shaperenderer-efficiency-on-games), but since I've got no answer yet, I decided to give a try. It's working nice so far but if you can use a texture, I'd say to go with that. (I'm not using a texture because I'm writing a small library and don't want to include non code).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Any comments on 2nd Question - about updating small regions of the screen?

Comment: @vintesh Sorry, but I really didn't get what you want to know there. English isn't my primary language.

Comment: I want to know that suppose i have rendered the whole grid/screen using the Texture but now suppose i want to change the one rectangle area then what should i use... ? I am using 
`code`
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(texture, x,y,x,y);
spriteBatch.end();
`code`
but i failed to get change the rect.

Comment: @vintesh just to be sure, are you making that second call inside the `draw()` method? perhaps if you shared you code it would be easier to help.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/vintesh/robo-puzzle)
I am unable to update the position of TILE of the grid that code is  in "app.game.robo.objects.renderer" package.

Comment: @vintesh Ok, I ran your code and everything seems to be drawing except the batch inside `drawArrowsAt()`, which isn't being called from `draw()`. I recomend you edit your question and add exactly the behavior you are intending and what is stopping you.

Comment: I am in developing game exactly like [Robozzle](http://www.robozzle.com/). & for that in `drawArrowAt` i want to move the arrow in particular direction & in that i am not able to render/animate the arrow. That's where i got stuck. & "Thanks for all your help"